# UV unwrapping the exterior of a hollow cylinder

Tags: uv

I'm pretty new to blender, and only have some idea of what I'm doing when it comes to UV unwrapping. Basically I'm trying to add a texture to the exterior of a hollow cylinder, but every time I unwrap it it also unwraps the interior which is not what I want.

Screenshot:
[image: As you can see the interior of the cylinder (which has a solidify modifier) is also being unwrapped]

Could the solidify modifier I put on the cylinder be causing this issue?

Comment: Yes, you should apply your Solidify modifier so that the inner side will be a different, to be able to give it another texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [solidify modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html) generates a second surface parallel to the original and a rim surface that joins the two together. You can configure the modifier to use a different material for each of these two surfaces with the original surface using a third material.

We can create multiple materials for each object, the materials in this list can be referred by an index that starts at zero, so the first material is index zero, the second index one and the third index two.

[image: materials by index]

In the solidify modifier, we can set the index for the second surface and the rim surface, the original surface will use index zero.

[image: solidify modifier assigning materials]

In this example, the generated surface is on the inside, we can [change the direction of the normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html#editing) to make the new surface be on the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Apply your Solidify modifier so that the inner side will is different, now you are able to give it another texture.